# Recursive selection sort error 11 when ordering big integers

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, selection-sort, function-definition

I have to use the recursive selection sort in order to order different arrays of integers.
These arrays are respectively formed by 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 200000, 500000 items and can be formed by ordered numbers, partially ordered numbers, inverted ordered numbers and random numbers.
After that I have to calculate the time the algorithm took to order the array.

I have to use recursion, It's a homework.

I created a function that generates the array:

```
typedef enum {ORINATO, INVERS, PARZ_ORDINATO, RANDOM} Ordine;

int *generaArray(int dimensione, Ordine ordine) {
int i, j, n;
int *array = (int*)malloc(dimensione * sizeof(int));

if (!array){
    return NULL;
}

switch (ordine){
    case ORINATO:
           for (i = 0; i < dimensione; i++){
            array[i] = i;  
        } break;

    case INVERS:
        n =0;
        for ( i = dimensione-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            array[i] = n;
            n++;
        }break;

    case PARZ_ORDINATO:
        for (i = 0; i < dimensione/2 ; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        for (j = i+1; j <dimensione; j++){
            n = rand();
            array[j] = n;
         };break;
    case RANDOM:
        for ( i = 0; i <= dimensione ; i++) {
            array[i] = rand();

        }break;
    
    default:
        break;
}
return array;
}
```

And it works like wonders.
Then I have created the recursive selection sort like follows:

```
void recursiveSelectionSort(int *array, int dim, int start){
int min=0;
if (start >= dim-1){
    return;
}
min = findMin(array, start, start+1, dim);
swap(&array[min], &array[start]);
recursiveSelectionSort(array, dim, start+1);
}

int findMin(int *array, int min, int start, int dim){
     if(start == dim ){
         return min;
     }
     if (array[start]< array[min]){
         min = start;
     }
    return findMin(array, min, start+1, dim);

}
void swap (int* x, int *y){
int temp = *x;
x =  *y;
y = *temp;
}
```

Now, this as well should work but something clearly isn't. Let's make an example with the implementation, this is what i put in my main:

```
int main() {
    int *array;
    
    clock_t start, end;
    double t;

    array = generaArray(1000, ORINATO);

    start = clock();
    recursiveSelectionSort(array, 1000, 0);
    end = clock();
    t = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nIl tempo impiegato per 1000 elementi è: %lf secondi", t);
    return 0;
   }
```

This works (but it's slower thank it should be). However if you try and change the dimension from 1000 to 200000 or 500000 it shows error 11.

What is it causing it? I tried everything but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are probably overflowing the stack.  Recursion may not be a practical solution here.  Why do you want to do this with recursion, rather than iterating?  Probably anything that can be done with recursion can be done another way.

Comment: @Basya It's a homework, i have to...

Comment: I see.  And....as I should have said before commenting, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you... do you have any idea on how to make it work? If I do that in the iterative way it works like a charm

Comment: You were specifically instructed to use recursion, with a recursion level per-element, for such large numbers?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's crazy, it is to confront it with the iterative version...

Comment: Do you still have the problem when you fix the bug that Vlad in Moscow pointed out?

Comment: yes, the swap function was always correct in my code, i typed it wrong on here, my bad...

Comment: The fact, that you are running out of stack memory, maybe exactly the thing you are supposed to learn from this exercise. On linux you can use `ulimit -s new_stack_size_in_kb` to amend the stack size temporarily.

Comment: OK, just checking.  It looks to me that there is some misunderstanding of the assignment; the recursion depth looks problematic, for such large arrays.  The example data with 1/ the array random and 1/2 not might be a clue that the array is to be split in 1/2, and in 1/2 again, or some such.  But that sounds like a different sort algorithm...

Comment: Actually guys, they specifically told us it  should work in both ways, I thought it was that as well but meh... I'm not sure anymore

Comment: Can you check with the instructor that you are understanding the requirements of the assignment correctly?  Something sounds strange here...

Comment: Selection sort recursive is stupid :) - something that can divide the group by 1/2 each time will roughly limit stack space to log2(n).  This is O(N) so your stack will need to be megabytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

For starters recursive functions called for large arrays can invoke a stack overflow.

So use non-recursive functions that implement the method selection sort for large arrays.

As for your implementation then for example the function `swap` has typos.

```
void swap (int* x, int *y){
int temp = *x;
x =  *y;
y = *temp;
}
```

I think you mean

```
void swap (int* x, int *y){
int temp = *x;
*x =  *y;
*y = temp;
}
```

All other functions have too many parameters.

For example the function `findMin` can be declared the following way

```
size_t findMin( const int *a, size_t n );
```

and can be also defined as a recursive function (if you decided to write recursive functions then this function can be also recursive)

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the functions can be defined

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap( int *x, int *y )
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x =  *y;
    *y = temp;
}

size_t findMin( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t i = findMin( a + 1, n - 1 ) + 1;
        return a[i] < a[0] ? i : 0;
    }
}

void recursiveSelectionSort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        size_t i = findMin( a + 1, n - 1 ) + 1;
        
        if ( a[i] < a[0] ) swap( &a[0], &a[i] );
        
        recursiveSelectionSort( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 15 };
    int a[N];
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % N;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    recursiveSelectionSort( a, N );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
11 9 3 5 6 8 2 4 5 3 7 9 2 0 14 
0 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 9 11 14
```

Comment: I already found something pretty much like this on a blog but the recursive selection sort functions I use in my program are the ones they gave us and I must use them actually... as per the swap one you're right i made a typo ahah

Comment: And my problem is JUST with big numbers, anything else works.

Comment: @crost As I wrote in my answer using the recursive function for large arrays results in stack overflow.